# Running django tests with sqlite

Tags: django, django-testing

I use Postgres for production and development, but I'd like to use sqlite to run some tests.  I don't see an easy way to configure one engine for tests and another for dev / production.  Am I missing something?

Comment: For now, I'm using this solution, although it seems dreadfully hacky:

http://seanhayes.name/2010/01/09/test-database-django/

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Append the following lines in your settings:

```
import sys
if 'test' in sys.argv or 'test_coverage' in sys.argv: #Covers regular testing and django-coverage
    DATABASES['default']['ENGINE'] = 'django.db.backends.sqlite3'
```

Make sure your actual database setting comes before them.

Comment: As I said in the comment, this is essentially what I'm doing now.  But don't you think this solution has a bit of the suck?

Comment: I saw your comment just after adding this post :) Nevertheless, this solution is perfectly fine for testing purposes: You run manage.py with a 'test' argument, Python passes it to the code via sys.argv, and the code behaves accordingly. I see nothing unpythonic here, do you?

Comment: Well, what if I'm not running manage.py?  I might be running django-admin.py some other way or using PyUnit or who knows what else?  My point is that django needs to be *aware* of its test database.

Comment: But no, I can't say it's unpythonic per se.

Comment: This solution will behave well as long as it receives 'test' as an argument from the command line. OTOH you're right, it would be nice if django provided a way to differentiate test settings. There we have issues more troubling than database settings, for example if your tests manipulate dirs or files under MEDIA_ROOT that's where you'll need hacky stuff.

Comment: Set ENGINE to 'django.db.backends.sqlite3' to avoid a deprecation warning with recent versions of Django.

Comment: ^^ And make sure engine is in capitals: 'ENGINE'

Comment: Caution with this `"test" in sys.argv`; it may trigger when you don't want it to, e.g. `manage.py collectstatic -i test`. `sys.argv[1] == "test"` is a more precise condition that should not have that problem.

Comment: Word of caution: You can't use a statement like `Thing.related_object.distinct('field_of_related_object')`—it will work in Postgres, but SQLite doesn't support calling distinct on fields (so if anything you're testing does this, it'll fail when using an SQLite DB)

Comment: Also adding DATABASES['default']['NAME'] = ':memory:' speeds up tests

Comment: Just for the record if you do this, make sure to switch your main database back to sqlite first and then make migrations before it'll work or you will get table/columns errors.

Answer (score 11):

This is not a direct answer, but yes, you are missing one big problem - testing a Postgres app on SQLite is tricky - they are **so** different. I suggest you rather create a ram-disk (e.g. using [tmpfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmpfs)) and create your Postgres test database there. It won't be as fast as SQLite, but possibly an order of magnitude faster than regular Postgres database stored on HDD.

Comment: Well, most tests don't do anything that differs from one engine to another.  In my experience, 9/10 (or more) tests use only the most straightforward manager methods.  So, to address your concern, I'd be fine with specifying for particular tests that I want to use postgres.  But if I just want to run the test suite in the field (and not be connected to the DB), I really need to be able to do that.  That's pretty basic.

Comment: I don't get this answer. In what ways are Postgres and Sqlite so different that a typical Django application (I assume it is using ORM) can't be reliably tested on Sqlite, or another database? Aren't we talking about a database-agnostic application here?

Comment: @shanyu: Noone forces you to belive me, if you have different experience then I'm perfectly fine with this.

Comment: @Tomasz: Why not share your experience? All in all I may be missing something.

Comment: Ok, let me reconsider and change the word "worthless" - which fits projects I've been working on - to word "tricky".

Comment: Ok guys, I've tried sqlite after a long time and either it improved meanwhile or I had some tricky cases last time I used it. Anyway, it looks good enough to perform quick tests on the fly, and switch to MySQL/PostgreSQL only once in a while to confirm that tests work with them as well.

Comment: @shanyu and what if the app has a JsonField in one of the models? This is an excellent answer as it highlights a flaw in the OP's plan, and provides a solution the problem the OP was presumably trying to solve through their plan (i.e. performance)

Comment: @shanyu One problem I just ran into: SQLite doesn't allow you to call `distinct` on specific fields while Postgresql does

Answer (score 4):

You could try a setup similar to what is suggested here by Zachary Voase:
  http://blog.zacharyvoase.com/2010/02/03/django-project-conventions/

(The entire post is useful, but scroll down to the section on "Settings" for the part most relevant here.)

Zach's strategy is to create a settings folder and marks it as a python package using a `__init__.py` file. You can then have a separate sub-module for each of your deployment types, structured as follows:

```
settings/
|-- __init__.py     # Empty; makes this a Python package
|-- common.py       # All the common settings are defined here
|-- development.py  # Settings for development
|-- production.py   # Settings for production
|-- staging.py      # Settings for staging
```

Following this concept, you could set up a deployment for postgres and a separate deployment for sqlite, and separate the configurations for each as needed.

Answer (score 4):

I think modifying the settings.py with `if 'test' in sys.argv` as suggested is a hack and doesn't work for example when you want multi-threaded test execution in pytest.
I think a better way would be to create a separate settings_test.py and adding
`DATABASES['default']['ENGINE'] = 'django.db.backends.sqlite3'` to it.

When using Django's testframework, execute your tests with `python manage.py test --settings=myapp.settings_test`

When using pytest, create a `pytest.ini` and insert

```
[pytest]
 DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = myapp.settings_test
```

Answer (score 1):

I've end up by adding the following in my settings.py.
The --keepdb will setup the Sqlite DB in RAM.

```
if 'test' in sys.argv:
    for db_test in ['default']: # Add other DBs if needed
        DATABASES[db_test]['ENGINE'] = 'django.db.backends.sqlite3'
        if '--keepdb' in sys.argv:
            DATABASES[db_test]['TEST']['NAME'] = '/dev/shm/' + db_test + '.test.db.sqlite3'
```